# Why drinking is prohibited in Islam?

Tags: halal-haram, alcohol, health

I have this doubt since a long time. Some of my friends said that it (drink) will affect your mind  and your body. This may be correct when we drink a large amount of drink. Even if we drink a very small amount of drink it will not affect our mind and scientists say that which is good for our health.

So small amount of drink is allowed?

Or else what is the correct reason behind this?

Comment: note that the scientists doesn't say it is good even with a small amount Anymore.

Comment: @KIllse  http://sciencenordic.com/three-beers-day-keep-doctor-away,http://www.medicaldaily.com/7-health-benefits-drinking-alcohol-247552

Comment: If you look at the references added in the article, they are pretty OLD. That's why I said most scientists do not hold these opinions anymore. For instance newer information can be found here: http://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/health-and-families/health-news/drinking-more-than-one-glass-of-wine-or-pint-of-beer-a-day-increases-cancer-risk-a6801806.html

or here: https://www.cancer.gov/about-cancer/causes-prevention/risk/alcohol/alcohol-fact-sheet

There are other studies: CAN; AMPHORA-studie, cancer report 2014. I have also read that one glass wine per YEAR is too much.

Comment: the article (in swedish) http://www.aftonbladet.se/nyheter/article18913492.ab saying one glass per year is even too much.

Comment: There are many drinks that we can drink, and God gives us infinite knowledge and power and wisdom, telling us that this one, Nohsh, surely knows that this is not good.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

A long answer is available at Islam Q&A, [article 40882](https://islamqa.info/en/40882).  In this case, the Qur'an itself provides an explanation:

> They ask you about wine and gambling. Say, "**In them is great sin and [yet, some] benefit for people. But their sin is greater than their benefit.**" And they ask you what they should spend. Say, "The excess [beyond needs]." Thus Allah makes clear to you the verses [of revelation] that you might give thought.  -- [Qur'an 2:219](https://quran.com/2:219)

I guess it's analogous to "Should you run a red light if no cars are coming?".  Perhaps it would be safe for careful individuals to run red lights, and one might even argue that running red lights has benefits (e.g. it aids traffic flow).  But I feel it's accepted that this is an overall bad idea, as it could result in harm.

What about just a little?

> Narrated Jabir ibn Abdullah:  If a large amount of anything causes intoxication, a small amount of it is prohibited.   ([sunnah.com](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/27/13))

If alcohol weren't prohibited in small amounts, it leads to a [paradox of the heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorites_paradox): How many drops of alcohol can you consume before it becomes haram?

Also, different people have different tolerances: what's a small amount for one person, is over the top for another.  And "one glass of wine" so easily turns into "two glasses of wine", leading to bad decisions.

(Note that alcohol in small amounts indeed affects our mind; see e.g.  [There is no such thing as a safe level of alcohol consumption](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2011/mar/07/safe-level-alcohol-consumption).)

Comment: "If a large amount of anything causes intoxication, a small amount of it is prohibited", what about food like uncooked rice? it can cause intoxication, so small uncooked rice is haram?

Comment: +1 good answer. And simple rules are easy to follow. No drink in islam thats the simple rule. For a better life,

Comment: @Rafid By intoxication it's meant to have psychedelic effects like hallucinations. And in general, anything that harms the individual is forbidden.

Answer (score 3):

Prohibited as proven in Quran:

> Say, “My Lord has only forbidden immoralities – what is apparent of
>   them and what is concealed – and sin, and oppression without right,
>   and that you associate with Allah that for which He has not sent down
>   authority, and that you say about Allah that which you do not know.”

So Allah has forbidden immoralities. This is clearly the case here:

> They ask you about wine and gambling. Say, “In them is great sin and
>   [yet, some] benefit for people. But their sin is greater than their
>   benefit.”

As you read in these verses, Allah has forbidden it because their sin is greater than their benefit. Also in another text:

> O you who have believed, do not approach prayer while you are
>   intoxicated until you know what you are saying

So as a muslim you can't pray while being "drunk".

Comment: And since you need as a moslem to be able to pray at any time, no alcohol then.